# How to move object within Row to edge of screen in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've made a `Row` containing 2 different items but I want the item on the right to be positioned on the edge of the screen. I tried using weights with the weight modifiers (`modifier = Modifier.weight(...f)`) but the results are not accurate enough. I also couldn't find any horizontal alignment features.

In the attached screenshot there is still plenty of space to the right of the `Switch` that can be used to move it to the edge of the screen (on the right).

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    Text(text = "My custom switch", modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
    Switch(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using weight on first composable inside of Row:

```
var switchState by remember { mutableStateOf(value = false) }

Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(weight = 1f),
        text = "My switch"
    )

    Switch(
        checked = switchState,
        onCheckedChange = { switchState = it }
    )
}
```

Using SpaceBetween on Row:

```
var switchState by remember { mutableStateOf(value = false) }
                        
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    Text(text = "My switch")

    Switch(
        checked = switchState,
        onCheckedChange = { switchState = it }
    )
}
```

You can apply a background to Text and Switch to see the difference involved in these two implementations.

With weight: 
[image]

With SpaceBetween: 
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like:

```
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    Text(text = "My custom switch", modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterEnd){
        Switch(checked = true, onCheckedChange = )
            }
        }
    }
```

Maybe change the `.fillmaxwidth` of the modifier, but `contentAlignment` is what you are looking for I think.